# Python scraping through multiple recurring tags in html file

Tags: html, python-3.x, web-scraping

I have an html file with content that I am scraping through. I can't seem to get the code right to get the desired output.

```
<span class="class_1">1</span>
<span class="class 2">text one</span>
<span class="class_1">2</span>
<span class="class 2">text two</span>
<span class="class 2">text two b</span>
<span class="class 2">text two c</span>
<span class="class_1">3</span>
<span class="class 2">text three</span>
```

I want to have the output look like this:

```
1 text one
2 text two text two b text two c
3 text three
```

The trouble I'm having is the different classes that recur. Could someone help?

I haven't been able to get anything remotely close.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.groupby` to group various tags together (here in your example by the `class=` attribute):

```py
from itertools import groupby

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_text = """\
<span class="class_1">1</span>
<span class="class_2">text one</span>
<span class="class_1">2</span>
<span class="class_2">text two</span>
<span class="class_2">text two b</span>
<span class="class_2">text two c</span>
<span class="class_1">3</span>
<span class="class_2">text three</span>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, "html.parser")

data = []
for c, g in groupby(soup.select("span[class]"), key=lambda tag: tag["class"]):
    print(" ".join(tag.text for tag in g), end=" ")
    if c == ["class_2"]:
        print()
```

Prints:

```
1 text one 
2 text two text two b text two c 
3 text three
```